# How would you add Arduino WiFi Module using I2C or serial interface?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am new to Arduino prototyping. I bought an Arduino Automatic Smart Plant Watering Kit 2.0 thinking it was a shield to use with my Arduino Uno WIFI Rev 2.  However, it turns out to be a specially designed Arduino board with all of the components integrated together.

While the system works as designed, my goal is to stream the data to IBM Watson Studio, or some other third-party SaaS.

I welcome feedback to understand how it might be possible to integrate the ESP8266 WIFI module using either the I2C or Serial interface. Here is the sample code: https://www.elecrow.com/download/watering_kit.zip I used a Raspberry Pi to get access to the data and use it in a web/mobile application but I'd like to eliminate this element, if possible. [image]

Comment: esp8266 arduino core doesn't have a working I2C slave library. and 32u4 has Serial1

Comment: I appreciate the prompt feedback. so, maybe the better solution than connecting to a Raspberry Pi is to set up this Arduino board to communicate with another Arduino like the Wifi Rev2 or Arduino YÚN Rev 2?

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

Comment: why? you can attach esp8266 to Serial1 of this board (the "Serial interface" connector). (How did get the idea about Yun? Forget Yun.)

Comment: okay, it's forgotten! I am grateful for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would connect the ESP8266 to the serial port.  The normal way of working with an ESP98266 is to issue AT command (like an old Hayes modem) through a serial connection. Since you have one of those available on your board it is a simple matter to just wire it directly to it.

Just follow any of the myriad of ESP8266 + Arduino tutorials, substituting the pins in the examples for your serial pins, and use the `Serial1` object instead of the `SoftwareSerial` class that you have to use on an Uno that lacks extra serial ports.